# Detect if class or ID is being used in HTML files. Does this software exist?

Tags: css

I'm wondering if there is software (preferably an Atom package) that can look at my css files, make a list of classes and IDs, and then search a selection of HTML to see if those classes and IDs are being used. If they aren't you would have the option to delete them.

This would help clean up CSS files with ease.. Does this kind of thing exist out there?

Comment: It's not that simple. For example, JS code could be adding a class to an element at run-time. So you cannot do this analysis statically. However there are dozens of tools to analyze your CSS as you run and identify unused rules. A quick search should turn up lots of them.

Comment: Check out the aptly named [unused-css.com](https://unused-css.com/). The page also lists 8 similar services.

Comment: Thanks guys, this helped me refine my search query and I ended up finding helium-css, which did the trick quite well. However nothing I found was _very_ elegant - it would be great to see something like this in an Atom package in the near future.